# "java.lang.NullPointerException" appeared in the process of netty4 test

Tags: java, netty

I just wantted to test the quantities of the lasting connnect of TCP supportted by netty4.When the quantities reached 1337, a new information appeared in client-side like below

---

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.setUpdateEvents(EPollArrayWrapper.java:178)
>     at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.add(EPollArrayWrapper.java:227)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.implRegister(EPollSelectorImpl.java:164)
>     at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.register(SelectorImpl.java:133)  at
>   java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel.register(AbstractSelectableChannel.java:209)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel.doRegister(AbstractNioChannel.java:285)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:438)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$100(AbstractChannel.java:373)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:417)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:354)
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:348)     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

---

client-side code is:

---

```
public class HSFTCPClient {

     private final String host;
     private final int port;


     public HSFTCPClient(String host,int port){
         this.host = host;
         this.port = port;
     }

     public void run() throws Exception {
            EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
            try {
                Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
                 b.group(workerGroup);
                 b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);

                  //Note that we do not use childOption() here unlike we did with
                 // ServerBootstrap because the client-side SocketChannel does not have a parent.
                 b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

                 b.handler(new HSFClientInitializer());

                // Make a new connection.
                 ChannelFuture f = b.connect(host, port).sync();
                 Channel ch = f.channel();

            } finally {
                     //workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            }
        }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          String host = args[0];
           int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
           int num = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

           for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
                    try {
                                new HSFTCPClient(host, port).run();
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
           } 
    }
}
```

HSFClientInitializer is:

```
public class HSFClientInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
           ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
            p.addLast("frameDecoder", new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());
            p.addLast("protobufDecoder", new ProtobufDecoder(NetMessage.getDefaultInstance()));

            p.addLast("frameEncoder", new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender());
            p.addLast("protobufEncoder", new ProtobufEncoder());

            p.addLast("handler", new HSFTCPClientHandler());
    }

}
```

HSFTCPClientHandler is:

```
public class HSFTCPClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<NetMessage> {

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, NetMessage msg)
            throws Exception {
          if(msg==null){
              return;
          }
          int msgType = msg.getMessageType();
          switch (msgType) {
              case 200:

            break;
        }

    }


     @Override
        public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {

           Channel ch = ctx.channel();

           ChannelFuture future=  ctx.newSucceededFuture().addListener(new ClientConnectListener());
        }


    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {

           ctx.fireChannelInactive();
           ctx.disconnect().addListener(new ClientDisConnectListener());
    }

}
```

ClientConnectListener is:

```
public class ClientConnectListener implements ChannelFutureListener {

    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
        Channel ch= future.channel();

        NetMessage.Builder msgBuilder = NetMessage.newBuilder();
        msgBuilder.setMessageType(100);

        System.out.println("-------client send netMsg ----------");
        ch.writeAndFlush(msgBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

ClientDisConnectListener is:

```
public class ClientDisConnectListener implements ChannelFutureListener {

    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("-------  disconnect-----------");
    }

}
```

client-side jvm params:

> /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java -Xms4G -Xmx4G -XX:NewSize=3584m
>   -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:SurvivorRatio=1 -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -classpath "./bin:./lib/*" com.test.protobuf.client.HSFTCPClient **.**.**.**(ip) 10007 10000
>
> Linux info: Tasks: 374 total,   1 running, 373 sleeping,   0 stopped, 
>   0 zombie Cpu0  :  0.3%us,  0.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,
>   0.0%si,  0.0%st Cpu1  :  0.3%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st Cpu2  :  0.0%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st Cpu3  :  0.0%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st Cpu4  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st Cpu5  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st Cpu6  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st Cpu7  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,
>   0.0%st Mem:  32865072k total,  2735996k used, 30129076k free,   345764k buffers Swap: 35110904k total,        0k used, 35110904k free,
>   1362400k cached jdk version: java version "1.7.0_40" Java(TM) SE
>   Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)

How can I fix the bug? and adjust the client-side code?

I really hope Netty can keep at least 50 thousand TCP Connect lasting in one server.

Answer (score 0):

Thats interesting... can you open a bugreport and add info how to reproduce it. Thanks!

https://github.com/netty/netty/issues?state=open

After more research I was able to find the root cause and come up with a patch for the JDK. So to make it shorts its a JDK bug.

See: 
http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nio-dev/2013-September/002284.html